Las benditas listas en java
Verán tengo (en java) un lista de tipo Pronostico donde puede haber pronósticos de tipo FraseDia, FraseFutura y Suerte.
Cuando el usuario pide por ejemplo una frase, debería retornar una FraseFutura random (una nueva frase es una nueva clase de tipo FraseFutura).
Bien ahora como hago para retornar de esa lista un frase de tipo FraseFutura, porque en la lista tengo FraseDia, FraseFutura y Suerte, osea, está todo entreverado, y no quiero crear una lista para cada objeto, total, todos son de tipo Pronostico.
Debe de haber alguna forma, el maldito GPT no sabe nada... acá les dejo el código (el método a enfocarse es mostrarPronostico), gracias Pibes:
package Obligatorio;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Adivinador {

    private Adivinador instancia;
    public List<Pronostico> pronosticos;
    
    public Adivinador(Class<? extends Pronostico> tipo) {
        mostrarPronostico(tipo);
        pronosticos = new ArrayList<>();                
    }
    
    public Adivinador getInstancia(Class<? extends Pronostico> tipo) {
        if (instancia == null) {
            instancia = new Adivinador(tipo);
        }           
        return instancia;           
    }
    
    public void addP(Pronostico p) { 
        pronosticos.add(p) ;            
    }       
    
    public void mostrarPronostico(Class<? extends Pronostico> tipo) { 
        System.out.println("Pronostico es:" ); 
    } //por ahora no uso tipo 
}


Puedes filtrar la lista y extraer únicamente los elementos del tipo Pronostico
deseado usando instanceof, después obtienes un elemento de tipo Pronostico aleatorio sobre la lista.
public void mostrarPronostico(Class<? extends Pronostico> tipo) { 
        List<Pronostico> filtrados = new ArrayList<>();
                    
        for (Pronostico p : pronosticos) { //* Filtra lista
            if (tipo.isInstance(p)) {
                filtrados.add(p);
            }
        }

        if (filtrados.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No hay pronóstico");
            return;
        }

        Random random = new Random();
        Pronostico pronosticoSeleccionado = filtrados.get(random.nextInt(filtrados.size())); //* Selecciona pronóstico aleatorio.
        System.out.println("Pronóstico seleccionado: " + pronosticoSeleccionado);
    }


Gracia. Si al final lo pude solucionar mas o menos de la misma forma, me ví obligado a crear una lista "filtrados" para hacer un random de eso. Pero ta, asi es java.. Gracias por tu respuesta bro!

No está muy claro tu código (no entiendo que debería hacer) así que me limito a una parte del mismo.
public Pronostico getPronostico( Class<? extends Pronostico> tipo ) {
   // recorremos el array y si hay coincidencia de la clase del objeto del mismo
   // y la recibida como parámetro, lo devolvemos
   for( int i = 0; i < pronosticos.size(); i ++ ) {
      if( tipo.equals( pronosticos.get( i ).getClass() ) ) {
         return pronosticos.get( i );
      }
   }
   // si no encontré correspondencia, devuelvo un objeto nuevo
   return new FraseFutura();
}

// a este método le cambié el nombre (agregué una "s"), lo uso para mostrar
// todos los pronósticos.
public void mostrarPronosticos() {
   for( int i = 0; i < pronosticos.size(); i ++ ) {
      if( pronosticos.get( i ).getClass().equals( FraseFutura.class ) ) {
         System.out.println( "Pronostico es: FraseFutura" );
      }
      if( pronosticos.get( i ).getClass().equals( FraseDia.class ) ) {
         System.out.println( "Pronostico es: FraseDia" );
      }
      if( pronosticos.get( i ).getClass().equals( Suerte.class ) ) {
         System.out.println( "Pronostico es: Suerte" );
      }
   }
} //por ahora no uso tipo

public static void main( String[] args ) {
   Adivinador aa = new Adivinador( new FraseDia().getClass() );
   aa.addP( new Suerte() );
   aa.mostrarPronosticos();
   System.err.println( aa.getPronostico( Suerte.class ).toStrng());
}


Gracias compa. Si, lo puse mas o menos, me faltó poner contexto, pero al final lo pude solucionar creando una lista donde contiene los pronosticos "filtrados"y de ahí hago el random. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Un placer maestro!!!
